# How to sort a merged array and hash chronologically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 app I have a polymorphic ActivtyFeed model.

```
class ActivityFeed
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :feedable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I need to aggregate some items in the ActivityFeed index view. For example, instead of rendering separate items for each photo, I want to group photos by a date or event, and display "User uploaded x photos".

My controller looks like this:

```
@feed_items = @user.activity_feeds.sort_by(&:created_at)
@feed_array = []
photos = @feed_items.find_all{|f|f.feedable_type.eql?("Photo")}
@feed_items.delete_if{|f|f.feedable_type.eql?("Photo")}
@feed_array << @feed_items
grouped_photos = photos.group_by{|p| p.feedable.event_id}
@feed_array << grouped_photos
@feed_array.flatten!
```

Then in the views I'm using e.g.

```
if feed_array.class.eql?(Hash)
  render grouped photo partial
elsif feed_array.feedable_type.eql?("Post")
  render single post partial
etc
```

I'm having trouble sorting items chronologically, because the array contains a nested hash.

```
[#<ActivityFeed id: 7, user_id: 2, feedable_type: "Post", feedable_id: 3>, {2=>[#<ActivityFeed id 3, user_id: 4, feedable_type: "Photo", feedable_id: 6>]}]
```

How can I sort this array?

I've tried `@feed_array.sort{|a,b| a.['created_at'] <=> b.['created_at'] }` but got `comparison of ActivityFeed with Hash failed`

Is this the best approach, or is there a better way to go?

Answer (score 5):

you can merge the array and the hash and then sort it

```
merged.sort {|a,b| a.method <=> b.method }
```

you only need to tell the sort how to sort the objects

one suggestion, instead of

```
@user.activity_feeds.sort_by(&:created_at)
```

do

```
@user.activity_feeds.order('created_at ASC')
```

that should be faster, since you already get the activities sorted from the database (if activity_feeds is a relation)

Comment: thanks @arielijuad. Sorry, I'm having trouble working out how to implement this. Say `@feed_array.flatten = [< ActivityFeed id:1 created_at:'second'> 2 => <ActivityFeed id:3 created_at:'first'>]`. Would I write something like `@feed_array.sort{|a,b| a.created_at ASC <=> b.???.created_at ASC}`? Thanks

Comment: @feed_array.sort{|a,b| a.['created_at'] <=> b.['created_at'] } seemed like it should work, but I get `comparison of ActivityFeed with Hash failed`. Any ideas?

Comment: if you can put some code to recreate your merged @feed_array array it would be easier, add the code to the question

Comment: thanks @arieljuod. ActivtyFeed has `:user_id, :event_id, :feedable_type, :feedable_id` attributes. I already have a description of how I'm creating the merged feed in my question. Let me know what extra info you need, and I;d be happy to add it. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: instead of merging the array with the hash, merge the array with hash.values, then you'll have an array only of ActivityFeeds and a.created_at <=> b.created_at will work

Comment: thanks arieljuod. Will I still be able to display the photos grouped by `feedable.event_id`? I'm thinking I may need to reevaluate my design, and include Event in the feed rather than photo. That way I wouldn't need to seperate and group the photos. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to do little bit modification to your original design.

What I would suggest is to add `event` to `activity feed` and also you need to keep the original `photo` to the `activity feed` as well.

Because, by keeping photo as a activity feed you will be able to display `a single photo`  on your activty stream when the photo is not associated with any `event`. But, if every `photo` belongs to an `event` then you can remove the `photo` from `activity feed`.

Then every object will be `activity feed` and can be sorted easily based on `created_at`.
Also you don't need to extract the photos manually.

Hope this will help!